# как оставить в файле только строки начинающиеся с конкретной буквы?

Tags: php, файлы

как оставить в файле только строки начинающиеся с конкретной буквы (php)?

Comment: показывай как пробовал и в чем конкретно проблема

Comment: использовав следующий код я удаляю первые три символа если они совпадают с заданными. а сейчас хочу его модифицировать или если есть другой более оптимальны способ чтоб удалял всю строку в файле если она начинается с задойного значения. может подскажете?
   `$lines = file($filename2);
    $lines = explode("\r", $buffer);
    $replaced = array_map(function($item) {
        return (strpos($item, '995') === 0) ? substr($item, 3) : $item;
    }, $lines);
file_put_contents($filename2, join("\r", $replaced));`

Comment: нажми кнопку "править" и добавь код в текст вопроса. И там его надо будет отформатировать

Comment: в целом, удалить строку из текстового файла можно только переписав его целиком, других вариантов нет

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вариант в принципе нормальный. Единственный минус он не будет корректно работать на `multibyte`-строках. Для этого замените `substr` на `mb_substr`. Также Вы не учитываете тот момент, что файл может быть очень большим по размеру и просто-напросто Вам не хватит выдеяемой под работу `PHP` памяти, чтобы поместить все строки файла в массив. В своем варианте я учел и то и другое замечание. Попробуйте его, возможно он Вам подойдет.

P.S Еще нужно учесть то, что при большом по размеру файле время работы `php`-скрипта может оказаться довольно длительным и он у Вас прервет свою работу т.к закончится максимальное время разрешенной для его выполнения. Для исключения этого, либо поправьте соответствующий параметр в `php.ini`, либо выставьте в начале скрипта флаг снимающий это ограничение. Это, с Вашего разрешения, я оставлю на Вас :)

> test.txt

```
995использовав следующий код 
я удаляю первые три символа если они совпадают с заданными. 
а сейчас хочу995 его модифицировать 
995 или если есть другой более оптимальны 
способ чтоб удалял всю строку в файле 
если она начинается с задойного значения. может подскажете?
```

> test.php

```php
<?php
$filename = "test.txt";
//Так как файл может быть большим, нам не подойдут
//file_get_contents и file
//открываем файл-источник на чтение
$fp = @fopen($filename, "r");
//файл открылся?
if ( $fp ) {
    //создаем файл для записи
    $fw = fopen("out.txt","w");
    if ( $fw ) {
        //читаем файл-источник пока не дойдем до конца файла
        while (!feof( $fp ) ) {
            $line = fgets( $fp );
            //С помощью регулярного выражения заменяем в каждой прочитанной строки
            //символы 995 вначале строки на пустоту тюе вырезаем их
            //символ "^" означает "строка начинается с" - ну а далее мы указываем наши символы "995" для отрезания
            $line = preg_replace("/^995.*?/", "", $line);
            //Сохраняем получившуюся строку в другой файл
            fputs($fw,$line);
        }
        //закрываем файл для записи
       fclose($fw);
        //закрываем файл-источник
       fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А как модифицировать, чтоб удоляли всю строку которая начинается на 995, а не просто эти символы в начале строки?

Comment: замените `$line = preg_replace("/^995(.*)/", "", $line);` на `if ( !preg_match("/^995(.*)/", $line ) ) {
                //Сохраняем получившуюся строку в другой файл
                fputs($fw,$line);
            }
`. По сути мы сделали так `если строка НЕ начинается на 995 - сохраняем ее в выходной файл`

Comment: К сожалению, первоначальный код не работает. Не удаляет 995 из строки.

Comment: `<?php
$fp = fopen($filename2, "r");
if ( $fp ) {
    $fw = fopen($upload_path . "out.txt","w");
    if ( $fw ) {
        while (!feof( $fp ) ) {
            $line = fgets( $fp );
            $line = preg_replace("/^995.*?/", "", $line);
            fputs($fw,$line);
        }
       fclose($fw);
       fclose($fp);
    }
}`

Comment: быть такого не может. я все что пишу проверяю.

Comment: Значит в моих заменах проблема. Разберусь. Спасибо вам за помощь.